# How to to use amp-analytics with sendBeacon payload as POST?

Tags: amp-html

I want to send analytics data to a custom URL using the sendBeacon API (transport `"beacon": true`). The payload encoded in the query string works well, but I want to put it into the POST body.

I tried the configuration as suggested in [PR #1162](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/1162), but then I realized it was not merged into [amp-analytics](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/871). Is there a way to configure it in the current implementation?

Comment: I have seen [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-analytics.html) that you can use [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) to transmit the request. This will send a POST request, with credentials, and an empty body. Here is the syntax: `navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);`. Note that MDM site states that this is an experimental technology.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
"transport": {
  "beacon": true,
  "xhrpost": false,
  "image": false
}
```

to your code.

A complete example looks like this:

```html
<amp-analytics>
<script type="application/json">
{
  "requests": {
    "pageview": "https://example.com/analytics?url=${canonicalUrl}&title=${title}&acct=${account}",
    "event": "https://example.com/analytics?eid=${eventId}&elab=${eventLabel}&acct=${account}"
  },
  "vars": {
    "account": "ABC123"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageview": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    },
    "trackAnchorClicks": {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": "a",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventId": "42",
        "eventLabel": "clicked on a link"
      }
    }
  },
  "transport": {
    "beacon": true,
    "xhrpost": false,
    "image": false
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```